# Conditional deletion of rows in large CSV files using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, csv, bigdata

I have a CSV file with headers containing more than 20 million rows and 39 columns. I want to delete all those rows for which value in column "age" is less than 18. How do I go about it in PowerShell?

Sample code:

```
Import-Csv 'test.csv' | Where { $_.age -ge 18 } | Export-Csv -Path 'adult.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

But this command is not giving the intended results and is deleting some rows with age<18 and keeping some. What am I doing wrong?

A sample of data could be accessed at this [link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzl56SYDK-iRLV9HTTlyMFFVZkU/view?usp=sharing).

Comment: CSV fields are strings so you need to convert it to a number: `[int]$_.age -ge 18`

Comment: PowerShell casts the second argument to fit the first. A string comparison of is done char ny char and then 9 is greater than 18. You could explicitly cast to an int as wOxxOm did or reverse the arguments (and the logic) to let powershell cast the 2nd arg to an int. `18 -lt $_.age`

Comment: @wOxxOm & LotPings Thanks!